# "dot net build" command is throwing error because of Package References in Next Js Starter Kit project for Sitecore 10.2

Tags: jss

I have downloaded the `Next JS` Starter kit for `Sitecore 10.2`, and adding cs files on it. I need to add Sonar cube, `build.yml` file in the solution. Sonar runs `dotnet build` and `dot net build` command fails because of package references in the projects, it is unable to locate the dlls. If we add the dlls directly as a reference, `dot net build` command works but if we use package reference, it fails. The starter kit comes by default with Package reference. Has anyone faced this issue? any pointers would help.